# RC-circuit transient SPICE simulation diverges after adding one capacitance

Tags: circuit-analysis, spice, ngspice

I tried to build a lumped parameter RC circuit model for an induction machine. The SPICE simulation worked fine for a steady state with no capacitances. Then I tried to add capacitance one by one as shown in the following figure (part of the model) to activate the transient simulation, the SPICE simulation diverged after I added the capacitance that was circled by the red pen in the figure, i.e., the voltage at different nodes increased exponentially and blew off. Could you please help me analyze what might be the possible reasons for such kind of error and how to fix it? Thanks!

P.S. It should be noted that the resistance value R_wd_3_cd_(i) is negative, I am not sure if this is the cause of the problem...If I delete this negative resistor from the circuit, the solution could converge, though to a wrong value.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Those current sources will act like integrators with a shunt capacitors, unless you have some resistance to ground to create a pole. If you're relying on the rest of the circuit for that, you're not showing it, and it can't be seen if there is a DC path to ground, or not (and what value). Not lastly, are you sure that's the place for the capacitor? What are you trying to model that you need that lumped RC?

Comment: What happens if you add the following as a text box on the schematic?  `.options rshunt=1g`

Comment: Thank you for the replies. The results still diverge after adding the global setting ".options rshunt=1g". There is a DC path to the ground as shown in the appended figure as shown in the question. It is through a voltage source from another node in the circuit to the ground. This lumped RC is a thermal network circuit for an induction motor. All the nodes indicate the temperature distribution of different components in this induction motor. The position of the capacitance is consistent with other literature on this topic, such as

Comment: Sciascera, Claudio, Paolo Giangrande, Luca Papini, Chris Gerada, and Michael Galea. "Analytical thermal model for fast stator winding temperature prediction." IEEE Transactions on Industrial Electronics 64, no. 8 (2017): 6116-6126. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7878526 The circuit in this article is also attached as the last figure in the question.

Comment: I also find that if I increase the resistance of R_st_wd_ct_(I) 30 times, the solution would converge, but of course to a wrong value.

Comment: @8cold8hot If it's an IM then that `Jloss` is not a simple current source, it's dependent on other quantities. It needs to be either a VCCS/CCCS or a behavioural current source. I would vouch for the latter, since the expression involves multiplication between the rotor currents. If you've only used a simple DC current source then it's to be expected for your voltages to "blow up". Also, "DC transient" analysis makes no sense: either it's a `.DC` analysis, or a `.TRAN`.

Comment: I modified the title to only retain the "transient". Actually here I use the analogy between a thermal circuit and an electronic circuit: power loss<->current source, temperature<->voltage, heat flux<->current. Jloss is provided other than calculated.

Comment: I think what's being asked is how you're implementing the \$J_{loss}\$ equation since it's dependent on the "voltage" of node 5.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFUqw.png

Comment: I agree with you that J_loss should depend on the temperature, while I hope to get the simulation to converge first and then add this extra temperature dependence, as I assume it is not the reason of the divergence of the solution?

Comment: Not sure, but it's possible that dependency creates a feedback which stabilizes the entire circuit.  It's tricky in general to solve convergence issues, but it's especially problematic in non-realizable circuits.  Most convergence issues are caused by some non realistic condition being implemented.  Some are solved with adding initial conditions (`.IC` command) because the circuit has more than one valid answer which it's bouncing in between, and the initial condition nudges it towards one and away from the others.

Comment: If you suspect something else is going one, I suggest pushing your netlist to another SPICE simulator and see if you get similar or different results.  This shows how to do it in KiCad 5 and LTspice, but not sure if the procedure/GUI changed in KiCad 6.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90Z6ffxzDz8&t=1318s

Comment: I tried with LTSPICE, but the result still diverges, same with setting all the nodes to an initial temperature 20 degree C.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K3WXPMhyL4YQKyTHBVvhmWp0N_uBQUsE/view?usp=sharing Here is the link to this KiCAD file if you are interested in looking into it.